# Vidyo - how to set logFileName to write in local file

Tags: vidyo

I want to set the logFileName parameter in CreateVidyoConnector (in a JS project), to write logs in a local file.

I read that logs are stored in (Windows) C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Vidyo\Data\User, but I don't have a Vidyo folder there...

**How can I see my logs?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebRTC browsers like Chrome or Firefox, you will not find any log files being created. You can see only console logs. This could be the reason why you can't find any.

Log files will only be created if you are using web plugin (Safari or IE10+). In this case, the log files are located in (Windows) C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp

The file names will be like VidyoClient.log, VidyoClient-0.log etc.